# What is causing Android Studio 3.1 - java.io.IOException: Failed to find byte code for javax/naming/Referenceable

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, build.gradle

### Problem Statement

When I add  the following, implementation project(':mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin'), dependency in my build.gradle of my Android Studio 3.1 project it Builds fine but gets the following failure when trying to run.

### Context:

Android Studio 3.1
MainActivity - Hello World;
mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin
The application will build successfully without any warnings
The application will not run with implementation dependency
the application will run with implementation dependency removed

### Here is the build.grandle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mysqlexampleproject2"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

testrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation project(':mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin')
}
```

### Here is the FAILURE:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:     java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException:    Failed to find byte code for javax/naming/Referenceable
```

### Here is the build.gradle for the MySQL connector:

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar'))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I take it you never found an answer. I have the same issue. Also floundering.

For reference this is the example project by Bill Butterfield https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bu5Y3uZ6LLM